# TFS query (in Visual Studio) to get all check-ins

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I'm trying to get a list of all check-ins (limited / ordered by date) via the TFS query editor in Visual Studio Team Explorer.

I can make a query that lists all bugs, sprint backlog item or product backlog item, but I can't find the actual check-in. Is it's possible or should I make (SQL) queries directly on the database.

Ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just open the Team Explorer window, expand the TFS project, and double-click the Source Control node there.

Then you can simply right-click a project or directory in TFS source control and select View History, then you'll get all the commits.

Answer (score 24):

The [`tf` command-line utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx) (available via VS2010 Command Prompt) provides a way to retrieve the history of all checkins for a specified file or folder.

Specifically, the [`tf history` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx) allows for filtering by date range.  For example, to get all of the checkins for the current month of June (i.e. 6/1/11 - 6/30/11), then use the `\version` parameter with the date option (`D"[start date]"~"[end date]"`):

```
tf history c:\MyProject /recursive /version:D"06/1/11"~D"06/30/11"
```

This will launch an interactive GUI window showing all checkins that occurred between those dates.  The GUI window is equivalent to the history windows shown in Visual Studio.  Therefore, you can drill down to view changeset details, compare to files to previous versions, etc.

If you simply want to view the history list without the GUI window then add the parameter `/noprompt`:

```
tf history c:\MyProject /recursive /version:D"06/1/11"~D"06/30/11" /noprompt
```

This will output the results to the command prompt console window.

Answer (score 11):

```
USE TfsVersionControl    

select distinct top 100 c.CreationDate,c.Comment,u.DisplayName, v.Fullpath
from tbl_changeset as c
 join tbl_identity as u on u.Identityid = c.OwnerId
 join dbo.tbl_Version as v on v.Versionfrom = c.ChangeSetId 
Order by c.CreationDate desc
```

Here is sql report I made to view recent changes.

Comment: I've tried numerous solutions over the last day in an attempt to solve this problem (Team Foundation Sidekicks, Windows Powershell, TFS Power Tools etc.) till i stumbled across your elegant solution. Many thanks for posting :-)

Comment: How to get the check-in action i.e. whether the check-in was for add, edit, delete, merge, etc.?

Comment: tbl_identity doesn't exist for me.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what we use

```
USE [Tfs_DefaultCollection]   

SELECT distinct cs.CreationDate, cs.[ChangeSetId], c.DisplayPart, cs.[Comment] 
from [tbl_ChangeSet] AS cs 
left outer JOIN [tbl_Identity] AS i ON cs.[OwnerId] = i.[IdentityId] 
left outer JOIN [Constants] AS c ON i.[TeamFoundationId] = c.[TeamFoundationId] 
left outer join dbo.tbl_Version as v on v.Versionfrom = cs.ChangeSetId 
WHERE creationdate > '04/12/2012' 
and (v.fullpath like '%\Web%' 
or v.FullPath like '%\Databases%')
ORDER BY cs.[CreationDate] desc
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out [TFS Sidekick from Attrice](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm). It is a very nice and free tool that I use regularly. It has a history sidekick that allows you to query changesets by user on the source tree node that you select on the left handside of the UI. You can sort the results by date. You can also right click on a changeset to see the details such the files and the workitems.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the history of a file or folder by right clicking on the file/folder in the solution explorer or source control explorer windows and then copy/paste the contents of the history if you want it somewhere else.

More interestingly in the use-case that you seem to be talking about, you can actually pull all this type of information in from the TFS Data Warehouse and do your own reporting on it in Excel.  Take a look at the following blog post I did on this topic for more information:

[Getting Started with the TFS Data Warehouse](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html)