# Browse all files for particular check in with TFS or VSO

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181408.aspx) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834150/3367144) explain how to view changes from within Visual Studio.  And within Visual Studio Online, navigating to `Code -> Changesets -> Changeset 1809` shows a view like this:

[image]

**But I want to browse *all files* from that particular point in time, not just changed files.** Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll have to download it locally to do that. In source control explorer you can right click on the project/branch and do get specific version

Comment: Hm.  That does seem like the closest I can get.  Thank you.